# SQL Coalesce with missing values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables, master and child. The master's primary key MM is an INT. The child table has a compound key of two columns and value column:

```
MM (INT)
POS (INT, values 1-32)
VV (INT, values 1-9)
```

Sample master table data:

```
(1, other data)
(2, other data)
(3, other data)
```

Sample child table data

```
(1, 1,2)
(1, 2,2)
(1, 4,1)
(1,15,1)
(2, 4,5)
(2, 5,3)
(2,31,7)
(3,3,1)
(4,18,2)
{4,19,5)
```

For a report I could like to de-normalize the data with an output like this:

```
(1,'22010000000000010000000000000000')
(2,'00053000000000000000000000000070')
(3,'00100000000000000000000000000000')
(4,'00000000000000000025000000000000')
```

I was thinking to use a select query with coalesce like this but the output is not not exactly what I want:

```
(1,'22110')
(2,'537')
(3,'1')
(4,'25')
```

How do I fill in the missing data with zeros?

Comment: Please tag your question with the acutal DBMS (vendor and version)

Comment: Server is MS SQL 2008 R2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way I can think to do this uses a decimal value with a precision of 32 and `sum()` and then convert back to a zero-padded string:

```
select mm,
       right(replicate('0', 32) + cast(sum(val) as varchar(32)), 32)
from (select c.*,
             cast(cast(val as varchar(32)) + replicate('0', 32 - pos) as decimal(32,  0)) as val
      from child c
     ) c
group by mm;
```

EDIT:

The above isn't generalizable (say, above 38 characters or to use letters as well as digits).  Here is a more generalizable, but longer version:

```
select c.mm,
       (max(case when pos = 1 then valc else '0' end) +
        max(case when pos = 2 then valc else '0' end) +
        max(case when pos = 3 then valc else '0' end) +
        . . .
        max(case when pos = 32 then valc else '0' end) +
       )
from (select c.*, cast(val as varchar(255)) as valc
      from child c
     ) c
group by c.mm;
```

I should note that if you want to handle a master with no children, then use a `left join`.  That aspect of the problem seems less interesting than combining the values in the appropriate positions.

Comment: What I love on SO, is the variety of approaches. Yours is definitely more elegant than mine! +1

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
DECLARE @master TABLE(MM INT,OtherData VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @master VALUES
 (1, 'Other Data 1')
,(2, 'Other Data 2')
,(3, 'Other Data 3');

DECLARE @child TABLE(MM INT, POS INT, VV INT)
INSERT INTO @child VALUES
 (1, 1,2)
,(1, 2,2)
,(1, 4,1)
,(1,15,1)
,(2, 4,5)
,(2, 5,3)
,(2,31,7)
,(3,3,1)
,(4,18,2)
,(4,19,5);
```

--One CTE to get 32 numbers

```
WITH Numbers(Nr) AS
(SELECT TOP 32 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM sys.objects) --get 32 numbers
```

--another CTE to get distinct MMs

```
,MMs AS
(
    SELECT c.MM
            ,m.OtherData 
    FROM @child AS c
    LEFT JOIN @master AS m ON c.MM=m.MM
    GROUP BY c.MM,m.OtherData
)
```

--In this CTE The CROSS JOIN with the Numbers will create a list of 32 rows, which carry in all positions with a corresponding child its number. COALESCE will set a zero in the place of all NULLs

```
,Masked AS
(
    SELECT MMs.MM 
          ,MMs.OtherData
          ,Nr
          ,COALESCE(VV,0) AS Val
    FROM MMs 
    CROSS JOIN Numbers 
    LEFT JOIN @child AS c1 ON c1.MM=MMs.MM AND c1.POS=Nr
)
```

-The final SELECT uses `FOR XML PATH` to get the 32 numbers in rows back to a string

```
SELECT *
      ,(
        SELECT Masked.Val AS [*]
        FROM Masked
        WHERE Masked.MM=MMs.MM
        FOR XML PATH('')
       )    
FROM MMs
```

The result

```
1   22010000000000100000000000000000
2   00053000000000000000000000000070
3   00100000000000000000000000000000
4   00000000000000000250000000000000
```

Comment: This seems to work except in the case where there is a master with no children?

Comment: That seems to work once I changed the selected fields to m.mm,m.otherdata and the group by to m.MM,m.OtherData